# Access multiple drives remotely

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, remote-desktop, cloud-storage

I've a feeling this is something that is going to be impossible, but thought I'd ask. I'm using Windows 10 Home - so Remote Desktop is out of the equation.

My current setup is C: which contains all the apps; this includes Apache/PHP. The server scripts I write are stored on the D: drive. I also have numerous extra drives (E:, F: ... U: {multiple partions} to store things like photos, music, video files, etc.).

Long story short, my back decided to go into sciatica, which makes it painful to sit on a chair to use a desktop PC.

But then I wondered if I could set things up so that a laptop could access the desktop PC's C: drive and other programs such as Photoshop. I did wonder about a standalone unit connected to the router, but that probably wouldn't work either.

Short of migrating the entire desktop C: drive to the laptop to give me a clone: that could give two D: drives, and also lead to two different sets of working files on two different machines. Maybe a standalone "storage drive" connected to the router so that laptop and desktop PCs save to one common file. Or failing that, D: drive on a USB flash drive that I can transfer from machine to machine. Unsure of this method as if the USB flash drive corrupts, everything is gone. Prefer USB flash drive as backup.

Oh, and any connection of laptop should be Wi-Fi rather than wired to allow freedom.

Another possible idea: the laptop can save to the D: to U: drives on the desktop PC. Again, not sure that would even be possible since "remote desktop" is not available.

Don't really know what I can try or even if it's possible. I've tried migrating my hard disk to laptop SSD before and it usually fails!

Any suggestions, or is this a "hiding to nowhere"?

Comment: I assume you've seen the [NHS sciatica page](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/sciatica/).

Comment: “I've tried migrating my hard disk to laptop SSD before and it usually fails!” Why does it fail? This seems like the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

- You can share your drives over the network. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYYe_Y-99fU
- You can use something that is similar but not the same as Microsoft Remote Desktop. For example TeamViewer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Z_K2KeSk7g
  You can configure it for unattended access.

Comment: If using TeamViewer, [Best practices for secure unattended access](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/108681-best-practices-for-secure-unattended-access) is important to follow. It's [been compromised](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/teamviewer-abused-to-breach-networks-in-new-ransomware-attacks/) more than once previously.

Comment: @AndrewMorton What does TeamViewer have to do with this answer?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 TeamViewer features heavily in the second point.

Comment: For your first point, could you address the OP's concern about "if I could set things up so that a laptop could access the desktop PC's C: drive and other programs such as Photoshop"?

Answer (score -3):

- You can upgrade Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro, if that's an affordable option.
- Some routers let you attach a drive via USB - is that what you meant? If so, find out if it they (the router USB interface and USB drive) will work at a decent speed. Or did you mean a NAS? Some NASes (e.g. Synology) let you run software on them, for example Apache and PHP.
- Note that most programs, for example Photoshop, will need to be installed on the machine they are run on, although the licence may allow installation on more than one computer, e.g. as shown in [On how many computers can I install my Adobe app?](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/download-install/using/install-apps-number-of-computers.html)
- It'll be a drive letter mess with that many drive letters, but you could get at least most of those drives mapped by sharing them on the host machine and using [`net use`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/gg651155(v=ws.11)) on the laptop.

If you aren't using source control for your server "scripts", you really need to. GitHub is a popular one, and using that gives you the ability to have them stored off-site as an extra backup.

Comment: `You can upgrade Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro, if that's an affordable option.` Why? What benefit would that give? There are quite a few programs that offer functionality similar to that of Microsoft Remote Desktop.

Comment: @Gantendo BitLocker might also be useful to the OP, but it's maybe a bit outside the scope of the question. You are of course free to give your own answer.

Comment: Why would bitlocker be useful???

Comment: @Gantendo Maybe the OP does freelance work and would like to be able to say they use encrypted drives for their data. Note that it was only one of my suggestions.